# SQL Server cannot connect via server name

Tags: sql-server, networking

Here the condition:

Let's say I have 2 SQL Server 2000 in my network :

1. sungai (192.168.1.63)
2. serverpc (192.168.1.200)

One of client PC can not connect to serverpc using "Computer Name" but works fine using IP Adress (ODBC and Query Analyzer), let say this PC as "Problem PC". 20 clients can connect to serverpc using Computer Name, just this "Problem PC" can't. "Problem PC" can connect to sungai using Computer Name and IP. I have checked nslookup and found no result using serverpc in my dns. This network using 2 router with 1 Subnet and Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry for asking. The problem is with Client PC.
Somehow there is sql server alias with name "serverpc" in this client PC.
I just remove it from "Client Network Utility" => "Alias" and works fine now.